# Scala class with generic types

Tags: scala, generics

I am trying to write a thin Scala wrapper around the Java Aws Lambda Client.

This class should accept 2 generic parameters:

- **An input type A** - which should be either a case class, which gets serialized to Json and sent to the Lambda function, OR Nothing/Unit type, in case the Lambda function intended to be called doesn't take any input parameters.
- **An input type B** - which should be a case class which is the actual deserialized Json->case class that the Lambda function returned, OR Unit in case the Lambda function doesn't return anything.

Something along the lines of:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvokeRequest
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.{AWSLambda, AWSLambdaClientBuilder}
import org.json4s.native.Serialization
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.{read, write}

class LambdaInvoker[A <: AnyRef, B <: AnyRef](val client: AWSLambda = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.defaultClient()) {

  implicit val serialization: Serialization.type = org.json4s.native.Serialization

  def call(input: A, function: String): B = {

    val request = new InvokeRequest().withFunctionName(function).withPayload(write(input))
    val result = client.invoke(request)
    val rawJsonResponse = new String(result.getPayload.array(), "UTF-8")
    read(rawJsonResponse)
  }
}
```

This works fine when I have both input and outputs to the call, but can't figure out what's the best "Scala" way of dealing with when A or B should not be present. I was looking for ways of getting the runtime type of A or B, checking against Unit, then base the logic on that, but couldn't find an obvious way (probably due to type erasure?)

If there is a different pattern I can apply here, without generic types but with Optionals, or anything else which achieves the same thing, that's also great.

Comment: This is great use case for a [**typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html) - basically I would write something like `class LambdaInvoker[A : Encoder, B : Decoder]`.

Comment: `Unit` is a subtype of `AnyVal`, not of `AnyRef`.

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified example of how you could use typeclass pattern. I'm going to define a local one that is responsible for both writing and reading an object

```scala
object LambdaInvoker {
  trait RW[A] {
    def addPayload(a: A, r: InvokeRequest): InvokeRequest
    def readResponse(r: InvokeResult): A
  }
```

Now, we need to define some instances (as implicits) with actual implementations. We have two cases: either it's Unit, and then we know how to handle that specifically, or it's something JSON-encodable.

To make everything work, we would have to use *implicit prioritization* technique of putting a fallback into a separate trait/class that we extend from. Here's a way to handle `Unit` by not doing anything at all:

```scala
  object RW extends RWFallback {
    // special cases go into this object
    implicit val unitRW: RW[Unit] = new RW[Unit] {
      def addPayload(a: Unit, r: InvokeRequest) = r
      def readResponse(r: InvokeResult) = ()
    }
  }
```

And our fallback will be using json4s. Json4s requires something called a `Manifest`, which is a part of a legacy scala reflection API, and we can require just that, without limiting ourselves to `AnyRef`.

```scala
  trait RWFallback {
    // fallback to json4s if not special cased
    implicit def fallbackRW[A: Manifest]: RW[A] = new RW[A] {
      implicit val serialization: Serialization.type = org.json4s.native.Serialization
      implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

      def addPayload(a: A, r: InvokeRequest) = r.withPayload(write(a))
      def readResponse(r: InvokeResult) = read(new String(r.getPayload.array(), "UTF-8"))
    }
  }
```

This all has been inside `object LambdaInvoker`, since it's limited to only LambdaInvoker stuff.

```scala
}
```

Now, for the implementation, you have to do the following:

- Require instances of RW for participating datatypes (done using implicit parameter list, or context bound syntax, e.g. `A: LambdaInvoker.RW`)
- Delegate to them in points where logic will vary depending on the type:

```scala
class LambdaInvoker[A: RW, B: RW](val client: AWSLambda = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.defaultClient()) {
  // "summon" the implicit values and give them a name, so we can refer to them
  private[this] val rwA = implicitly[RW[A]]
  private[this] val rwB = implicitly[RW[B]]

  def call(input: A, function: String): B = {
    // delegate serialization
    val request = rwA.addPayload(input, new InvokeRequest().withFunctionName(function))
    val result = client.invoke(request)
    // delegate parsing
    rwB.readResponse(result)
  }
}
```

Comment: One issue is that the json4s expects an AnyRef type when calling write(), and that seems not to go well with that Manifest type.
The signature of json4s' write is:

def write[A <: AnyRef, W <: Writer](a: A, out: W)

Comment: @cristi.calugaru could be. It seems that one in `native` package is different, but I don't use json4s, so I don't know if it's fine. You can use `<: AnyRef` as your bound if needed, the point here is more to demonstrate the idea.

Comment: Yep, I ended up doing that. I think this looks great - i'll adapt it a bit and get back.

Comment: Overall this put me on the right track and it was a good example to build on, hence accepting the response.
One a side note, coming from a java background, implicits, companion objects and other scala compiler goodies do feel like magic :)